# Woocommerce product variations "disappear" after programmatically changing status

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a script that updates prices of woocommerce products programatically.
Now I'm trying to disable/set private a variation if there's no price from my feed.

Here is the code:

```
$query = "UPDATE wp_posts SET
            post_status = %s
            WHERE ID = %s";
$result = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare($query, 'private', $post_id));
```

While the db seems to be updated correctly the changes are not reflected in wp. As a matter of fact the product variation disappears completely in both backend and frontend.

It seems like wp doesn't see the variation at all...

As a test I tried the reverse and set a `private` variation back to `public` with the same result.

I also tried to sync variations after updating the db with:

```
$_product = wc_get_product( $post_parent_id );
$_product->variable_product_sync();
```

or

`do_action( 'woocommerce_variable_product_sync', $post_parent_id );`

but the result is the same.

Does anybody have an idea what's happening here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

OK it's a f#*ng typo:

the correct value is `publish` not `public`